# Convert argv to a static string, or bug in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c, argv

I want to modify an old C code, that takes inputs from the commandline
to take a constant argv-vector of strings, defined from inside main.

I get a run-time exception

```
//void main(ac,av)
//char *av[]; 
void main()
{
    char *av[]= {"C:\\spice3f5.exe","input.cir","-r","output.txt",0};
    char  **tv;
    tv = av;
    tv++;
    **tv='-';// "Access violation writing location 0x00708edc."
    (*tv)[0] = '-';//Same runtime exception
}
```

This simply shouldn't happen...Is it a bug in Visual C++ 2010?

Comment: @timrau's answer is exactly correct. String literals enclosed in `"` are constant and stored in platform dependent, read-only static storage.

Answer (score 9):

The elements of `av` are pointers to string constants. Thus, modifying them leads to access violation.
This is not a bug of Visual C++.

Comment: To extend the answer, you should have defined const char* av[], then the compiler would have saved you before run time.

Comment: Thank you Josh. But I don't understand,

I don't think you´re right because
the original code below work.

This should also give an access violation, but doesn't. 

        void main(ac,av)
         char *av[]; 
         {
           char **tv;
           tv = av;
           tc = ac;
           tv++;          
           **tv='-';

The rest of the code needs av (=argv), and I thougt that
I could provide it as a constant array of strings,inside main.
But it just doesn´t work.

Comment: @user1535323 well you did say *old code* so chances are it was an old K&R compiler that allowed it. And also as you're counter-arguing with Josh above, with the code in your comment, using K&R C has a slightly different dialect to the ANSI C and should not be used. Rather more than, update the code to reflect the newer ANSI C standards.